# What did my dead English opthalmologist write that looks like pziou or pzio9?

Tags: medical

I received a registered mail of all my charts from my dead opthalmologist's office. He was Caucasian. He had yellow hair. He spoke English with  the Received Pronunciation.

I found this hand writing  but what does it mean?
I called his office, but they already disconnected their phone line. Any optometrists or ophthalmologists here?

1. Is this "oa"? "ou"? What does this mean?
2. Is this pzisou? pzjou?  pzio9? pzjo9?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that analysing handwriting is on-topic here.

Comment: I don't know what it means, but I think the second character in the final word is an ampersand, and the last might be a figure 9.  P&jo9, maybe? I don't know what it means, but googling shows many eyeglasses with JO9 in the description.  example: https://www.go-optic.com/caterpillar-ctoj09-eyeglasses-ctoj09/p/261416

Comment: Who cares what his hair colour was?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about the English language but about deciphering one individual's handwriting.

Comment: Looks almost like lesion - but yes, the best person to help might be a living optamologist

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I think it means borderline primary and inflammatory glaucoma both eyes. Definitely go see a specialist when you can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know what the apparent abbreviation "pzi09" stands for but according to [this website](https://timroot.com/eyeabbreviations/) "OU" means **oculus uterque** or **both eyes**.

I also know that "narrow angles" *can* be (although not always are) a symptom of at least one serious opthamological condition. I believe that your late opthamologist was referring you to another professional for further investigation.

I would advise you visit another opthamologist or consult a doctor as soon as you possibly can, take a printout of the document with you to the appointment and tell the opthamologist or doctor all the circumstances. I really would do this as quickly as you can.

Comment: I went to my optician 20 years ago for a test because I was worried about black dots at the edge of my vision. He did some tests and picked up the phone and called the local eye hospital. Both retinas were starting to detach. I would be blind in 1 to 2 years. I had a procedure 2 weeks later. This saved my eyesight. Surely the writer of the note would have done this or advised it?

Comment: "P&I" is [another ophthamological term](https://www.google.com/search?q=ophthalmology+p%26i) although it doesn't appear to have much to do with narrow angles.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Unless obstruction of the nasolachrymal duct can cause extra pressure in the eyeball. I don't know but I'd want to see an optical or medical professional ASAP.

Comment: It seems *very* likely that "ou" is used in both 1 and 2, so this is only a matter of understanding the first three letters.  PI *[could](https://www.aao.org/young-ophthalmologists/yo-info/article/ophthalmic-abbreviations-101)* stand for [peripheral iridectomy/iridotomy](https://www.brightfocus.org/glaucoma/article/peripheral-iridotomy-laser-procedure-narrow-angles), the straightforward laser procedure for narrow angles. Could 's" mean *two"?  (I see "PISOU" for the text) But that's a GUESS, not an answer!

Comment: @MikeSerfas based on what you said, the second one would be p&i ou , "peripheral iridectomy both eyes"

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have "&" in the middle for that.. the second letter doesn't look like how I've seen people write "&" in the U.S., but on this I should defer to someone from the other side of the pond!